# Error: Content is not allowed in prolog in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I tried to run following xsd validation in SoapUI using Groovy

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.*

// setup validator
Validator validator;

    def url = "file:///D:/SoapUI/XSDFile.xsd"
    log.info url
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    InputStream inp = uri.toURL().openStream();
try
{
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    StreamSource entitySs = new StreamSource(inp);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(entitySs);
    assert(schema != null);
    validator = schema.newValidator();
}
    finally
    {
    inp.close();
    inp = null;
    }

def response = context.expand( "file:///D:/SoapUI/response.xml" )

log.info response
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(response)))
```

But I am getting below error in the groovy step in the SoapUI test Case

```
:ERROR:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator$validate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:33)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As per solution given on the web I removed unwanted characters though I cannot see as such by converting file from UTF8 file to ANSI

But still giving the same error

Is this caused some other issue?

Response

```
<GeocodeResponse>
   <status>OK</status>
   <result>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
      <formatted_address>Rio de Janeiro, Brazil</formatted_address>
      <address_component>
         <long_name>Rio de Janeiro</long_name>
         <short_name>Rio de Janeiro</short_name>
         <type>locality</type>
         <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
         <long_name>Rio de Janeiro</long_name>
         <short_name>RJ</short_name>
         <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
         <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <address_component>
         <long_name>Brazil</long_name>
         <short_name>BR</short_name>
         <type>country</type>
         <type>political</type>
      </address_component>
      <geometry>
         <location>
            <lat>-22.9035393</lat>
            <lng>-43.2095869</lng>
         </location>
         <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
         <viewport>
            <southwest>
               <lat>-23.0830199</lat>
               <lng>-43.7954493</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
               <lat>-22.7490450</lat>
               <lng>-43.0993817</lng>
            </northeast>
         </viewport>
         <bounds>
            <southwest>
               <lat>-23.0830199</lat>
               <lng>-43.7954493</lng>
            </southwest>
            <northeast>
               <lat>-22.7490450</lat>
               <lng>-43.0993817</lng>
            </northeast>
         </bounds>
      </geometry>
   </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Schema file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://maps.googleapis.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://maps.googleapis.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="GeocodeResponse" type="_GeocodeResponse"/>
   <xs:complexType name="result_geometry">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="location" type="geometry_location"/>
         <xs:element name="location_type" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="viewport" type="geometry_viewport"/>
         <xs:element name="bounds" type="geometry_bounds"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="viewport_southwest">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lathjj" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="lng" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="bounds_northeast">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="lng" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="geometry_viewport">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="southwest" type="viewport_southwest"/>
         <xs:element name="northeast" type="viewport_northeast"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="geometry_bounds">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="southwest" type="bounds_southwest"/>
         <xs:element name="northeast" type="bounds_northeast"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="bounds_southwest">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="lng" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="viewport_northeast">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="lng" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="_GeocodeResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="result" type="GeocodeResponse_result"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="address_component">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="long_name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="short_name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="2"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="GeocodeResponse_result">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="2"/>
         <xs:element name="formatted_address" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="address_component" type="address_component" maxOccurs="3"/>
         <xs:element name="geometry" type="result_geometry"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="geometry_location">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="lng" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Appreciate your response

Cheers

Comment: Can you please post the test step response?

Comment: EJK thanks for your response. Do you mean to say you need the response XML file?. Because in this test case basically send the request with request header parameters and then get the response and try to do schema validation through groovy script.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm having troubling following.  Your comment above implies you are validating XML that is part of a test response (I assume this is a web service?).  However your code implies that you are validating the contents of a local file....  Regardless, the exception indicates that schema validation is failing when you pass it XML.  I would like to see the XML that is failing the validation.

Comment: Yes, This is a `REST web service ` where I save the response to local machine and then do the validation. I attached the both response and schema files to the question. Both xsd and response saved locally.

Comment: try adding an XML declaration to the file and see if that fixes the validation: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

Comment: Did changes as you proposed, but no luck. Same error

Comment: I checked whether any BOM characters are there in the file by opening it through HxD tool. But I don't see anything unusual.